# How do I delete a table row?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to make the following code work for the last 5-6 hours, but had no luck.

Can anyone please help me understand what's wrong with this code? After clicking on the delete link nothing happens.

Here is my table:

```
<table id="links">
    <tr id="record-<?php echo $row['FeePaymentId']; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $row['MasterEntryValue']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Amount']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('table#links td a.delete').click(function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")) {
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        var data = 'id=' + id ;
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "DeleteRow.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
            }
        });                
    }
})
```

Comment: Where's the error occur? And, what is the error?

Comment: nothing is happening after clicking in the delete button of table row!!!

Comment: Well, whats your dev console say? Is the AJAX call not entering the success function?

Comment: Are you sure your selector works??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code that would make the click event not happen as long as the code is executed ***after*** the table and it's rows exist.

Comment: I would add an error: function(e) {} in your ajax call so you can see if the PHP callback is throwing an exception.  It is possible that your success function is never called.  You can also add a complete: function() {} to notify you that it has completed.  This may help shed light on the error.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by nothing is happening? do you not get a confirm dialog?

Comment: If the click event is not firing you should try the solution provided by: user2405748.  $(document).ready(function() {})

Comment: I had an error in my answer so I deleted it, it's not helpful for this question. Anyway, instead to just criticize you could try to help a lil bit. You didn't posted anything useful already, @KevinB I suggest you to add an `error: function(){..}` to check if your problem is with your server. Also, use `alert` or `console.log(...)` and check if your variables have correct values. Use developers tools of your navigator to see if your information is sent correctly and in the correct format

Comment: @VinayKesharwani [**Your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4NsQ/3/) works as-is, please provide additional context to your question. Where is this code being executed? Is the confirm dialog popping up? what exactly is it not doing? nothing at all? is the confirm dialog popping up but then the row not going away? Are the rows dynamically generated?

Comment: After clicking the delete link...not even the alert is showing!!! I tried everything...put the javascript in the head section...but again no result!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your JS, if there are no other JS errors in the page and the click event is not firing at all. Than just place your JS code inside $(document).ready(function () {});:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table#links td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "DeleteRow.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });                
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector isn't correct, try this: `$('#links a.delete')` which will select all anchor elements with class 'delete' under the element with id 'links'

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4NsQ/)

Comment: The selector is more specific than it needs to be, but it isn't *"wrong"*

Comment: agreed, but i tried to keep it as close to the OPs initial code as possible.

Comment: No, i mean the OP's initial code isn't wrong, it's just too specific. making the change suggested here shouldn't have any effect. http://jsfiddle.net/B4NsQ/1/